# Remove observations according to a pattern in R

Tags: r, loops, pipe, row, delete-row

I have a dataframe with observations of injuries in soccer. Unfortunately I have several teams for each injury to choose from. This is what a section of the dataframe looks like:

```
df_x = data.frame(injury_id=c(250, 250, 100, 328, 328, 329, 329, 330, 330, 15, 5106, 5106, 5106),
 player_id=c(109, 109, 39728, 2374, 2374, 2374, 2374, 2374, 2374, 26, 59016, 59016, 59016), 
 season=c(2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2012, 2012, 2012), 
 inury_from=c("2011-09-13", "2011-09-13", "2011-03-03", "2011-04-21", "2011-04-21", "2010-11-23", "2010-11-23", "2010-10-01", "2010-10-01", "2011-02-24", "2012-09-16", "2012-09-16", "2012-09-16"),
 injury_until=c("2011-09-27", "2011-09-27", "2011-03-17", "2011-08-31", "2011-08-31", "2011-03-14", "2011-03-14", "2010-11-22", "2010-11-22", "2011-02-28", "2012-10-28", "2012-10-28", "2012-10-28"),
 team_id=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 member_since=c("1998-07-01", NA, "2009-07-01", "2008-07-01", NA, "2008-07-01", NA, "2008-07-01", NA, "2002-07-01", "2012-07-01", "2013-01-01", "2011-07-01"))
```

[image]

My goal is to have only one line for each injury_id. The following dataframe should come out as result:

```
df_result_x = data.frame(injury_id=c(250, 100, 328, 329, 330, 15, 5106),
 player_id=c(109, 39728, 2374, 2374, 2374, 26, 59016),
 season=c(2011, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2012),
 inury_from=c("2011-09-13", "2011-03-03", "2011-04-21", "2010-11-23", "2010-10-01", "2011-02-24", "2012-09-16"),
 injury_until=c("2011-09-27", "2011-03-17", "2011-08-31", "2011-03-14", "2010-11-22", "2011-02-28", "2012-10-28"),
 team_id=c(1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7),
 member_since=c("1998-07-01", "2009-07-01", "2008-07-01", "2008-07-01", "2008-07-01", "2002-07-01", "2012-07-01"))
```

[image]

The algorithm to select for observations with multiple injury_ids:

- delete lines that have NA at member_since.
- delete all rows whose member_since is later than injury_until.
- If duplicate observations remain choose the observation with the later date in member_since.

[image]

Can I do this via a pipe or do I have to use a loop?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 11-10-2020:**

```
df_x2 = data.frame(injury_id=c(250, 250, 100, 328, 328, 329, 329, 330, 330, 15, 5106, 5106, 5106),
                  player_id=c(109, 109, 39728, 2374, 2374, 2374, 2374, 2374, 2374, 26, 59016, 59016, 59016),
                  season=c(2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2012, 2012, 2012),
                  inury_from=c("2011-09-13", "2011-09-13", "2011-03-03", "2011-04-21", "2011-04-21", "2010-11-23", "2010-11-23", "2010-10-01", "2010-10-01", "2011-02-24", "2012-09-16", "2012-09-16", "2012-09-16"),
                  injury_until=c("2011-09-27", "2011-09-27", "2011-03-17", "2011-08-31", "2011-08-31", "2011-03-14", "2011-03-14", "2010-11-22", "2010-11-22", "2011-02-28", "2012-10-28", "2012-10-28", "2012-10-28"),
                  team_id=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7),
                  member_since=c("1998-07-01", NA, "2009-07-01", "2008-07-01", NA, "2008-07-01", NA, "2008-07-01", NA, "2002-07-01", "2013-01-01", "2011-07-01", "2012-12-31"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `slice` after grouping by 'injury_id'

```
library(dplyr)
df_x %>%
    group_by(injury_id) %>%
    slice(1) %>% 
    ungroup
```

or with `distinct`

```
df_x %>%
      distinct(injury_id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Or if the `NA` elements are not in order, do an `arrange` on the 'injury_id', followed by the logical vector based on NA elements in 'member_since' (so that NAs will be last) and the `Date` converted 'member_since' and then use `distinct` to select the first unique row based on the 'injury_id' column

```
df_x %>%
    arrange(injury_id, is.na(member_since), as.Date(member_since)) %>%
    distinct(injury_id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

#### Update

Based on the comments

```html
df_x %>%
    filter(!is.na(member_since)) %>%
    mutate(injury_until = as.Date(injury_until), 
          member_since = as.Date(member_since)) %>% 
    mutate(ind = injury_until - member_since) %>% 
    group_by(injury_id)  %>%
    filter(ind == min(ind[ind > 0])) %>%
    select(-ind)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
# Groups:   injury_id [7]
#  injury_id player_id season inury_from injury_until team_id member_since
#      <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <date>         <dbl> <date>      
#1       250       109   2011 2011-09-13 2011-09-27         1 1998-07-01  
#2       100     39728   2010 2011-03-03 2011-03-17         3 2009-07-01  
#3       328      2374   2010 2011-04-21 2011-08-31         4 2008-07-01  
#4       329      2374   2010 2010-11-23 2011-03-14         4 2008-07-01  
#5       330      2374   2010 2010-10-01 2010-11-22         4 2008-07-01  
#6        15        26   2010 2011-02-24 2011-02-28         6 2002-07-01  
#7      5106     59016   2012 2012-09-16 2012-10-28         7 2012-07-01
```

Comment: But with injury_id = 5106 the correct line could also be at the last position. It is only coincidence that the first one must be selected here.

Comment: @edstrinova I added the `arrange` before the `distinct`.  Does it help

Comment: Not the latest date of member_since is the correct one. It is important to check how the date member_since is related to injury_until. If the member_since is later than injury_until, the observation can be deleted.

Comment: @edstrinova can you update with another example so that it will be easier to test. thanks

Comment: I test a little with your suggestion and then build another example. But you are right, even with a changed order, your solution still seems to work. Great! I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: I have already found an error with the above example. With your code the wrong observation remains at injury_id 5106.

With you it will be team_id = 9, but it should be team_id = 7.

Comment: @edstrinova For that id, `2011-07-01` is for 'team_id` 9, but `2012-07-01` is still before `2012-09-1`. Are you looking at the 'season' column

Comment: It is like I said in the description: If duplicate observations remain choose the observation with the later date in member_since. The player 59016 moved from team 9 to team 7 at the beginning of the season (probably 07-01-2012) and was injured while he was with team 7. In the second half of the 2012 season he moved to team 8.

Comment: Many thanks for the new code. With df_x and df_x2 (changed last 3 observations) it works!

With 500 on 60000 observations I have the phenomenon that the column injury_until is NA. This is because the injury is still active. Is there a way to integrate this fact into the code?

Comment: @edstrinova perhaps, you need to take account of the NAs with `min(ind[ind > 0], na.rm = TRUE)`